# How to embed Cocoa Touch Framework in Xcode 7

Tags: ios, xcode7, cocoa-touch

I try to add a test framework to a text app in Xcode 7, but it fails.

> ld: framework not found TestUtility clang: error: linker command
>   failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Any idea what is going on? A have cleaned, removed subfolders in`~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData`.

I show some screen shot, but nothing special I have set. Here is an empty Cocoa Touch Framework built for iOS 9.

[image]

Here is the TestApp, set embedded as usual

[image]

And the error:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Follow these steps:

1. Create your custom framework in Xcode. Close it.
2. Create the project for your application. Close it.
3. Create a workspace for your application. Make sure that your project is added. If not, choose "Add files..." then add your *.xcodeproj
4. Add your custom framework to your workspace using the same way in **step 3**.
5. In your workspace, click your application project and under the "TARGETS", choose your application project (scheme), expand the “Linked Frameworks and Libraries”
6. Drag your *.framework found under the tree of your custom framework in your workspace to the location stated in **step 5**
7. Enjoy! :)